# React-router - forcing one route everywhere?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have quite simple React + Redux app using react-router.

There is a main menu and 4 main routes:

/main
/profile
/games
/pay

As the app starts I'm dispatching an action and if the action returns `force_pay = true` I want all the routes to point to /pay so user is generally not able to do anything within the app excepting going to /pay component. Once he pays I'm dispatching another action that will unblock the routing.

Is it doable with react-router? Is changing routes dynamically a good idea? How would you handle it? I was thinking about redirecting user to different pay-only version of my app and then once payment is done redirecting him again to the full-access app, but it might require refreshing the app and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: completely doable with react-router. changing routes dynamically is perfectly fine and super easy with react router 4. many applications do this since the url in modern apps is really just a global variable.

Comment: keep in mind, that "forcing the route" is essentially the same thing as just setting some state and only rendering components related to payment. if you don't need to share that link or return to it later via url, then the current route / url behaviour is kind of irrelevant